# how to disable the input field on selection of "IsEmpty"?

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-if="query.field.operatorClass == 'CharOrNull'" class="ng-scope">
    <!-- ngIf: selectedOperator[$index] == translatedIsEmpty -->
    <!-- ngIf: selectedOperator[$index] != translatedIsEmpty -->
    <input ng-if="selectedOperator[$index] != translatedIsEmpty" ng-model="query.value" class="form-control ng-valid ng-scope ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" maxlength="1">
    <!-- end ngIf: selectedOperator[$index] != translatedIsEmpty -->
    </div>
```

When this condition `ng-if="selectedOperator[$index] != translatedIsEmpty"` fails, i need to hide the input field.. i have used ng-show instead of ng-if that did not solve the problem.. Also added the condition in the div

```
div ng-if=("query.field.operatorClass == 'CharOrNull'") && query.field.operatorClass <> "IsEmpty" class="ng-scope">
```

still it does not work for me.. How to fix this?

Comment: What is 'translatedIsEmpty'? If it's a string it should be `!= 'translatedIsEmpty'`

Comment: Another point is that you are using `<>`, it should be `!=`, no? Would be great if you provide your JS code...

Comment: How would we know? You haven't provided enough details regarding variables or view context See [mcve]

Comment: TranslatedIsEmpty is "IsEmpty" string Enum value

Comment: When in doubt it's really simple to output those variables right in the view to see what they actually contain. Also note that `ng-if` creates child scope

Comment: I am new to angular, on the same code any change would bring me what i wanted?/

Comment: As I and @charlietfl said, you have to put more details (such as your JS code) in your question.